# Apache + Passenger App route with multiple apps and different configs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I've have a ruby on rails app under `/var/www/html/rq/` which by default grabs config from the directory above it..

```
TEMPLATE = YAML.load_file("../brand.yml")
```

I've have since created two virtual hosts

- `crayon.domain.com` pointing at `/var/www/html/crayon/public/`
- `icb.domain.com` pointing at `/var/www/html/icb/public/`

Both public folders contain a brand specific `brand.yml`.

Both virtual hosts have `PassengerAppRoute` set as `/var/www/html/rq/` so there is only one version of the code base, which is running under `Rails 3.2.8`

Depending on what virtual host they come in on, I want it to pick up the brand file for that domain. I tried

```
TEMPLATE = YAML.load_file("/brand.yml")
```

and

```
TEMPLATE = YAML.load_file("http://localhost/brand.yml")
```

hoping it would pick up the file from the specific public folder, but it seems to be reading from the RAILS APP public folder under `/var/www/html/rq/public`.

Anyone got any idea of how I can achieve what I need to and have one application with two public folders and two sets of config?

Comment: What Rails environments are these virtual hosts running under?

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.8 if thats what you mean?

Comment: No, I mean what environment name are they using - are they both running under 'production'?  Or does each virtual host have separate environment names/databases/configurations?